# Create a filter on arbitrary properties dynamically

Tags: javascript, code-generation, odata, jaydata

Example of what I'd love to be able to do:

```
query.filter(function (person) {
    return person[this.field] == this.value;
}, {
    field: 'FirstName',
    value: 'Lea'
});
```

This throws an exception as of JayData 1.3.2.
Note that hard-coding the property name with `[]` syntax works as expected (although not useful):

```
query.filter(function (person) {
    return person['FirstName'] == this.value;
}, {
    value: 'Lea'
});
```

1. Is this possible without eval() trickery?
2. If not, is there any kind of alternative?

**Note:** Using the OData provider, if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah, it is not supported
query.filter() has an alternative format:

```
  query.filter('it.something == this.something')
```

so with some string concat can achieve what you want

```
  query.filter('it.'+field+' == this.value', { value: 'Lea'})
```

Comment: How can you do contains instead of ==